# R - Obtaining the highest/lowest value in a set of columns defined by the value in a different dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, data-manipulation

I have two dataframes: one (A) containing the start and end dates (Julian date, so a continuous count of days) of an event, and the other (B) containing values at dates from start to beyond the end dates in the first dataframe. The start date in A is stable, the end date varies.

I want to be able to, for each row, identify the value with the greatest **magnitude** of change *(highest and/or lowest values)* between the start and end date  in the series in B, then write to a new dataframe.

Example dataframes

```
dfA <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,5), 
                  startDate = rep(1001,5),
                  endDate = c(1007, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006))

dfB <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                  "1001" = c(0.5,0.3,1,2,1.1),
                  "1002" = c(0.9,0.3,0.5,1.0,1.2), 
                  "1003" = c(0.8,0.3,0.1,1,2), 
                  "1004" = c(1,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.1), 
                  "1005" = c(2,1,3,1,4), 
                  "1006" = c(1,0.5,0.1,0.3,2), 
                  "1007" = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                  "1008" = c(0.5,1,2,1,0.3))
```

So, for `ID = 1`, I want to find the lowest value in B between `1001` and `1007`, the start and end dates. This would then be repeated as `ID = 1,2,3...n`

Is there a solution in the tidyverse package for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by Matt's answer, but taking highest and lowest values **inside** the time interval (as I understand the question):

```
test2 <- left_join(dfA, dfB, by = "ID") %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(ID, startDate, endDate)) %>% 
  mutate(name = str_remove(name, "X")) %>% 
  filter(name >= startDate & name <= endDate) %>% #here we keep only the rows with name between startDate and endDate
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(highest = max(value), 
         lowest = min(value)) %>% 
  select(ID, highest, lowest) %>% 
  distinct()
```

Comment: Thanks, this does pretty much exactly what I needed. Do you think there would be a way to grab the value with greatest absolute difference relative to the start and end date? For instance, if `start = 1 & end = 1` with intermediate values of `0.5, 0.3, and 2` I want to find the value with greatest variation from start and end. It could be the highest or lowest number, but the number furthest from start and end. Does that make sense?

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you want to do. Which number would it be in your example?

Comment: It would be 2, since it is 1.0 greater than the start/end compared to being 0.5 below or 0.7.

Comment: Sorry mate I'm loaded with work atm. I guess you could follow the same idea and add columns for value at start, value at end, and the difference with the actual value. Then filter to keep only max values.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what your expected output should be, but here's a `dplyr/tidyverse` approach by joining dataframes:

```
library(tidyverse)

    left_join(dfA, dfB, by = "ID") %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(ID, startDate, endDate)) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(name = str_remove(name, "X"),
         highest = max(value), 
         lowest = min(value)) %>% 
  filter(name <= endDate)
```

This gives us:

```
     ID startDate endDate name  value highest lowest
   <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1      1001    1007 1001    0.5       2    0.5
 2     1      1001    1007 1002    0.9       2    0.5
 3     1      1001    1007 1003    0.8       2    0.5
 4     1      1001    1007 1004    1         2    0.5
 5     1      1001    1007 1005    2         2    0.5
 6     1      1001    1007 1006    1         2    0.5
 7     1      1001    1007 1007    1         2    0.5
 8     2      1001    1003 1001    0.3       2    0.3
 9     2      1001    1003 1002    0.3       2    0.3
10     2      1001    1003 1003    0.3       2    0.3
11     3      1001    1004 1001    1         3    0.1
12     3      1001    1004 1002    0.5       3    0.1
13     3      1001    1004 1003    0.1       3    0.1
14     3      1001    1004 1004    0.8       3    0.1
15     4      1001    1005 1001    2         4    0.3
16     4      1001    1005 1002    1         4    0.3
17     4      1001    1005 1003    1         4    0.3
18     4      1001    1005 1004    0.9       4    0.3
19     4      1001    1005 1005    1         4    0.3
20     5      1001    1006 1001    1.1       5    0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

If all dates in range are present as vectors in dfB:

```
# Enure all dates in range have a corresponding vector in dfB copy:
jdrng <- seq(min(dfA$startDate, na.rm = TRUE), max(dfA$endDate, na.rm = TRUE))
prod_df <- merge(dfA, dfB, by = "ID")

# Calculate vector indicies to be used in roc, max and min value calcs:
vnidx <- which(grepl("^X\\d+", names(prod_df)))
strtidx <- vnidx[match(prod_df$startDate, jdrng)]
endidx <- vnidx[match(prod_df$endDate, jdrng)]

# Calculate moc, max and min vals:
res <- cbind(ID = prod_df$ID, do.call(rbind, Map(function(x, y, z) {
  data.frame(moc = (x[, z] - x[, y]) / x[, y],
             maxval = max(unlist(x[, y:z]), na.rm = TRUE),
             minval = min(unlist(x[, y:z]), na.rm = TRUE))
}, split(prod_df, prod_df$ID), strtidx, endidx)))
```

If not:

```
# Ensure all dates in range have a corresponding vector in dfB copy:
jdrng <- seq(min(dfA$startDate, na.rm = TRUE), max(dfA$endDate, na.rm = TRUE))
jdvecs <- as.integer(gsub("\\D+", "", grep("^X\\d+", names(dfB), value = TRUE)))
if(!identical(jdrng, jdvecs)){dfB[,paste0("X", setdiff(jdrng, jdvecs))] <- NA_real_}
prod_df <- merge(dfA,
                 dfB[, c(names(dfB)[!grepl("^X\\d+", names(dfB))],
                         paste0("X", sort(jdrng))),], by = "ID")

# Calculate vector indicies to be used in roc, max and min value calcs:
vnidx <- which(grepl("^X\\d+", names(prod_df)))
strtidx <- vnidx[match(prod_df$startDate, jdrng)]
endidx <- vnidx[match(prod_df$endDate, jdrng)]

# Calculate moc, max and min vals:
res <- cbind(ID = prod_df$ID, do.call(rbind, Map(function(x, y, z) {
  data.frame(moc = (x[, z] - x[, y]) / x[, y],
             maxval = max(unlist(x[, y:z]), na.rm = TRUE),
             minval = min(unlist(x[, y:z]), na.rm = TRUE))
}, split(prod_df, prod_df$ID), strtidx, endidx)))
```